Stuck on the TWRP splash screen, Odin not detecting device?
I installed LineageOS on my Samsung M20. After installing it removed the TWRP. However, I needed TWRP to install MAGISK so I flashed the TWRP image again but this time the phone is stuck on the TWRP splash screen.
It can only reboot (Power + Volume down), it isn't detected by ODIN nor can I enter download mode, therefore only the Samsung boot logo and the TWRP splash screen.
